# Bruteforce using crunch and Aircrack (custom starting number?)

Tags: wifi, brute-force, wireless

I'm trying to do a Bruteforce attack on a handshake taken from my wireless network that is not WPS enabled. The reason I'm doing it is because I'm testing how strong a 10 digit phone number is as a password. I tried the following command

```
crunch 10 10 0123456789 | aircrack-ng -e NETWORK -b 60:C3:97:34:8B:E9 -w- hs/NETWORK.cap
```

But that took too long. I'm wondering if there is a way to start the attack **after** the first 3 digits of the password. Here they would be "760". I tried

```
crunch 10 10 7600123456789 | aircrack-ng -e NETWORK -b 60:C3:97:34:8B:E9 -w- hs/NETWORK.cap
```

But that starts with "777". Any help getting "760" first would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

crunch 10 10 0123456789 -t 760%%%%%%% | aircrack-ng ...........

where 760 are the first three characters and the percents are any possible number. Meaning % stands for any number after 760

for lower-case letters replace % with @
for upper-case letters replace % with '
for symbols replace % with ^